# Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code that keeps giving me an error... I use it on other pages and it doesn't produce this error.

`$('.viewFrame').on("click", function(){`

I have `jQuery 1.11.0` and migrate `1.2.1` libraries imported.

Link to page : https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/constantContact/citizen/cmpi.aspx

Comment: Have you tried debugging this using the developer tools of your browser, or an extension like Firebug? Also: if you post a link to a live page where you see this error, it's much easier for us to take a look at and see if we can understand why this happens.

Comment: It seems the reuired js file is not included.

Comment: Did you run this code when jquery is not yet loaded?

Comment: You are including the wrong version of jQuery. On the page in question, you must be including an older version.

Comment: @TomasLycken linked to page. I have the script load at the end of the page and I have the libraries imported at the top of the page.

Comment: You did realize that you went back right. 1.11 is greater than 1.2.1. `on` came to existence only >1.4

Comment: @KevinB if you look at page resources and at scripts it says jquery-1.11 and migrate 1.2.1

Comment: On the page you linked, in _jqueryLoader.min.js_, it says `/*! jQuery v1.6.4 http://jquery.com/ | http://jquery.org/license */` not `1.11.0`...

Comment: @metsales Please see the comment I made above. It does not say jQuery 1.11.0

Comment: @karthikr 1.2.1 is not a jquery version in this case, it's a jquery **migrate** version.

Comment: @metsales To be quite honest I'm suprised any of it works. In my console I've got version 1.6.4, 1.7.1 and 1.11.0. This is some seriously hacky code.

Comment: @War10ck the people who built the framework of our site didn't do it so well. It was kind of like how windows was, instead of fixing the old code they just created work arounds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the page you linked, in *jqueryLoader.min.js*, it says:

```
/*! jQuery v1.6.4 http://jquery.com/ | http://jquery.org/license */
```

**not** version 1.11.0. The `.on()` method was not defined until version 1.7.

**EDIT:**

After further investigations, it appears you are loading two versions:

1. 1.11.0
2. 1.6.4

In the order listed above. As @AWolff stated in his comment below, the last version loaded is the version used. In this case 1.6.4 is loaded ***after*** version 1.11.0, so `.on()` will be undefined.

Comment: so then why doesn't it work if 1.11 is still imported?

Comment: @metsales The jQuery version used would be the last one included. You are including jQuery 1.6.4 version in last and anyway you should never include more than one jQuery version, doesn't make sense especially if you are using jQuery migrate

Answer (score 2):

You're running jQuery **1.6.4**, but you need at least **1.7**

To prove this fire up the JS console and type in `$.fn.jquery`

Answer (score 1):

You're loading jQuery twice in your application. At the top you have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

and later on you have:

```
<script src="https://www.metsales.com:443/MetropolitanSales/Script/jQuery/jqueryLoader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The second one is overwriting the jQuery loaded by the first one, and it contains jQuery version 1.6.4, which doesn't have `.on()`.

Remove this second script, it shouldn't be needed.